# SSIS: Value does not fall within the expected range. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)

Tags: ssis, etl

We copied an SSIS project from one server to a new server. Now we can not debug/run any of the packages and getting below errors:

```
Failed to start project (Microsoft Visual Studio)

===================================

Exception deserializing the package "Value does not fall within the expected range.". (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
Program Location:

at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(Boolean isRemoteTest, IVsDebugger iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchActivePackage(Int32 launchOptions)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)

===================================

Value does not fall within the expected range. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)

------------------------------
Program Location:


at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Interop.ProjectInterop.GetPackageByName(String bstrPackageStreamName)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSProject100.GetPackageByName(String bstrPackageStreamName)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DebugEngine.DtsProgramNode.CreateRuntimePackageInternal(IDtsHost& host, Process& process, Package& dtsPackage)
```